# How to return a char array constant member from a class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, char

I'm trying to code a sort of command-oriented approach for an Arduino project. So I have a List that represents a queue of Commands, I also have a Command class that provides the structure for all the commands that inherit from this parent class.

Since I wanted to achieve a simulated concurrency, the queue gets iterated over to call the exec() method from every command (exec() is an overridable method provided by the Command class that executes an action). Since some commands will perhaps use the same physical resource from Arduino (actuator, sensor etc.), I don't want those commands executing concurrently, I want only the first one in the queue to get executed, so the next one waits until the previous is done and so on.

In order to solve this issue, I added to the Command parent class, a virtual method called "getReq()" that should return a char array, where every char constant represents a physical resource from Arduino that is needed for the command to work. (I made it virtual so that every command that inherits from Command, can return its own char array).

The goal is that when I iterate over the queue, I'll call only once the getReq() method and then check if at least one of the char constants is contained in a global List that contains all the char constants / Arduino Resources that are being used right now, so that if it finds a coincidence, it won't execute the command cuz at least one of the command requirements is being used.

The problem is, getReq() doesn´t work. I'm sorry, at this point I'm so desperate that I've tried a lot of things, so I've gotten all types of compile errors, I'm not asking for an error in particular, but a way to achieve what I described above.

The command class:

```
  class Command {

  // Clase Command, es la clase virtual que provee la estructura para el resto de comandos
  private:
  int state = 0; // Estados: 0 = NOT_EXEC, 1 = NOT_READY, 2 = NOT_FINISHED, 3 = FINISHED
  
  
  public:
  virtual void init() = 0; // Función de inicialización de comando
  virtual void exec() = 0; // Función de ejecución del comando
  virtual void finish() = 0; // Función de finalizado del comando
  virtual ~Command(){};
  void setStatus(int s){ 
    state = s;
    };
  int getStatus(){
    return state;
  } // Entrega el estado del comando

  virtual char* getReq() = 0;
  
  
};
```

A sample command (focus on the char array r[10] and the getReq() method)

```
class InitWifi : public Command{
  private:
  
  
  public:
  static char r[10] = {'A', '\0'};
  InitWifi(){
  }
  void init() override{
    
      
  }

  void exec() override{
    // Serial.println("Configurando WiFi");

    // Serial.println("Terminada configuración de WiFi");
  setStatus(3); // Terminar comando
  }

  void finish() override{

    
  }

  char* getReq() override{
    return r;
  }

  
  
};
```

The control loop (Only focus on the INIT and EXEC cases from the switch clause)

```
const int INIT = 1; 
const int EXEC = 2; 
const int MAIN = 3; 
int state = INIT;
long init_time;
long t;
List<Command*> queue = List<Command*>();
List<char> Requirements = List<char>();
char* commandReqs;
bool willRemove = false;


void loop() {
  // Máquina de estados para control global de la estructura orientada a comandos
  switch(state){
    case INIT:
      // Inicialización de la máquina de estados
      init_time = millis(); // Obtener el tiempo en el que la máquina de estados se empezó a ejecutar por primera vez.
      t = init_time;
      queue.Add(new InitWifi()); // I'm queueing a command here
      state = EXEC; // Realizar transición a ejecución de comandos.
      break;
    case EXEC:
      // Ejecución de comandos en cola
      if(queue.Count() > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.Count(); i++){
          switch((*queue[i]).getStatus()){
            case 0: // NOT_EXEC
              commandReqs = (*queue[i]).getReq(); // Obtener requerimentos.
              // Verificar si los Requerimientos del comando estan ocupados.
              if(!isAvailable(commandReqs)){
                // En caso de que el comando requiera dependencias que no están disponibles...
                break;
              }
              for(int z = 0; commandReqs[z] != '\0'; z++){
                Requirements.Add(commandReqs[z]); // Apartar los requerimientos del comando
              }
              (*queue[i]).init();
              (*queue[i]).setStatus(2); // Cambiar estado a NOT_FINISHED

              break;
            case 1: // NOT_READY
            
              break;
            case 2: // NOT_FINISHED
              (*queue[i]).exec();
              break;

            case 3: // FINISHED
              (*queue[i]).finish();
              commandReqs = (*queue[i]).getReq(); // Obtener requerimentos.
              for(int z = 0; commandReqs[z] != '\0' ; z++){
                Requirements.Remove(Requirements.IndexOf(commandReqs[z])); // Libera los requerimientos del comando para poder ser usado por otro comando
              }
              willRemove = true;
              break;
          }

          if(willRemove){
            queue.Remove(i);
            willRemove = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      state = MAIN;
      break;
    case MAIN:
      //=================== Aquí va el código principal ===================
    
      
      //=================== Aquí termina el código principal ===================
      state = EXEC;
      break;
  }

}

bool isAvailable(char* r){
  for(int i = 0; r[i] != '\0'; i++){
    Serial.println((int)r[i]);
    if(r[i] != '\0'){
      if(Requirements.Contains(r[i])){
        return false;
      }
    }
    
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Note: it's hard to do a text search for a variable named `r` to see how and where it's being used and abused. You should give it a more easily distinguished and descriptive name.

Comment: I get you.  In this case, `r` only appears within the `InitWifi` class (initialized as  a public static member and also within getReq() to retrieve its value), it shouldn't even be static, I did that just as I was melting down due to the compile errors.

Comment: Back up the program and start carving your way down to a [mre]. By the time I'd cut my way down to [something manageable](https://ideone.com/2bjA7S) I'd lost the error. And I don't even know what the error was. The `static` is a mistake, by the way. It's making things worse. Lose it if you can.

Comment: I opened your code, copied the way you initialize and return the char variables , I honestly dont know what's going on but it worked. However I'm committed to finding what happened before, so I'll work on the MRE and upload it if you or somebody else is interested on giving it a look.

Comment: MREs are a great tool. I can't speak for everyone answering questions here, but the reason I ask for them is MRE is actually a powerful debugging technique. If you didn't find and fix the mistake while making the MRE there's either a bit of information you don't have or you've got a question that's interesting enough to be worth preserving on the site for future programmers to learn from. Often both.

Comment: try `static const char* r = "A";`